# newScheduledThreadPool(1) creates multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

In my Java project, i want something to be done periodically, every minute. Investigations said that this is done with

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

and

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, interval, MINUTES);
```

So far, so good.
The executed task can take more time than my intervals length. In this case, the new task should wait. I thought that i did this by setting my threadPoolSize to 1 but it does not work. When my task takes much time and the next task should be executed because the interval time was over, it simply executes.

Can someone tell me how to make new tasks wait for earlier tasks termination?

Comment: Please provide an mcve.

Comment: If you need one thread, so you don't need a thread-pool.

Comment: @user5266804 A `ScheduledExecutorService` is more than just a thread pool.  And for that matter, a thread pool with only one worker is more than just a naked thread.  They have methods that do useful things, and you don't have to (re)write them.  It's foolish to re-implement things that the library gives you for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` with your requirements, from its javadoc:

> Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially.

Timer and TimerTask is an alternative solution for you.

Code sample, "Hi" will be printed once per 10 seconds, non 1 second.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
   executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Thr(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public static class Thr implements Runnable {

   @Override
   public void run() {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println("Hi");
   }
}
```

This solution will guarantee that you don't accidentally reconfigure pool somewhere, for example.
If use of `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` factory method instead of `newScheduledThreadPool(1)` doesn't help - mostly possible that you use another executor for scheduling or something like this. Take a look at your code, non Java executors or try to provide [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unfortunately, newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() seems to behave in the same way :/

Comment: @user2945914 It's impossible. Please, provide full code sample with non-consistent with javadoc behavior.

Comment: @user2945914 Provided code sample, works as it should and documented.

Comment: Can you explain why their current solution isn't working and why this is better?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis everything is in javadoc for this method. "Unlike the otherwise equivalent {@code newScheduledThreadPool(1)} the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads." If author will make executor this way and will use this executor for task scheduling and not another one - it guarantees no side effects of reconfiguration attempts. Author didn't provide code sample, so I don't know what does he do. With current solution is not important, it will just work.

Comment: So please it obvious in your question that you are  assuming they are doing something wrong, like reconfiguring the returned `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: Okay, i found the problem within my task. I put my task which takes a lot of time in a separate new Thread. Now it forks fine, thanks